# Java - PreparedStatements in Camel

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel, prepared-statement

I've been playing around with Camel for the purpose of getting to know it for a few weeks now. So far I have used a `SimpleRegistry` filled with a `DataSource` pointing to my SQLite DB to tell the `CamelContext` about the database. I use a bean to put my SQL statement together and then I just send it to a JDBC endpoint in a message. Used Java DSL for everything. This works fine.

Now my colleague wanted to know, why I don't use `PreparedStatements`. I did some research on what prepared statements are and now I'd like to test this with Camel.

I came across the camel JDBC component option called `prepareStatementStrategy`, as well as the interface `JdbcPrepareStatementStrategy` and it's implementation `DefaultJdbcPrepareStatementStrategy`. But I still don't understand, how to use them. Couldn't find an example.

Any suggestions on how to start or what to read?

Answer (score 1):

The sql component uses prepared statements

- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-sql/src/main/docs/sql-component.adoc

You can find some example using database/ sql at

- https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Also the mybatis component uses prepared statements as well, or elsql etc. And as well the JPA component but it uses the JPA abstraction over SQL which can be a bit overkill in some cases to work with, also the JPA component is not as flexible as some of the other database components.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a specific example from github instead of having a link to 100+ examples. It would fit the [answer] guide line too ;) Or simply an example of the notation.

Comment: Just look at that table it has a category where you can see 'Database'

Comment: I understand and already found the examples I need some time ago, but I was referring to the "[answer]" page about "_Provide context for links_". SO is based on the fact that a link can die/change. Which is why including a simple example is better.